# Format Data from MySQL Row for Download

Tags: php, download, formatting

I am looking to generate a downloadable file from a field in my database. This code currently does work, however it does not format the message correctly.

The row data is stored in the database in plain text with a `<br>` at the end of each line to display properly when it is accessed directly. I don't want to download the file with the `<br>` tags included in the file, so I created a new variable to replace the `<br>` instances with a `\r`.

When I download the file locally it works as expected. When I try it from another server, it removes the `<br>` tags but it does not add the `\r`.

```
   //Associate our data to the required row
   $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
   $data=$row['fldloginfo'];

   //Modify the returned data to include line breaks instead of html tags
   $spaces="\r";
   $brs="<br>";
   $formatted=str_replace($brs,$spaces,$data);

   // Print headers
   header("Content-Type: $data");
   header("Content-Length: $data");
   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file-log.txt");
   header("Content-Description: PHP Generated Data");
   header("Content-transfer-encoding: binary");

   echo $formatted;
```

Comment: Why would you use `\r` and not `\n` for line-break? Are you using an old Mac?

Comment: Isn't it a display issue? The \r are added, just on the remote computer \r is not considered a line break?

Comment: @Shadow I think it is a display issue. I noticed that if I open it with Notepad++ it displays correctly. Thank you.